# What is the meaning of the statistical gauge field in the fractional quantum Hall effect

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory, topological-order, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

I'm a grad student studying the fractional quantum Hall effect. To get started, I read chapter 9.5.1 of A. Altland and B. Simons' *Condensed Matter Field Theory*.
They use the composite fermion (CF) approach, where they attach two flux quanta to each microscopic fermion via a gauge transformation.
Their starting point is the microscopic Hamiltonian.

$$H = \int\text{d}^2 x  \frac{1}{2m} \psi^\dagger (-i\partial_x + \textbf{A}_{\text{ext}})^2 \psi  + V,$$

where $V$ is some interaction.
They apply the gauge transformation

$$ \psi(\textbf{x}) \rightarrow \psi(\textbf{x})\text{e}^{-i\chi(\textbf{x})}, \quad \text{where} \quad \chi =  2 s  \int\text{d}^2x'\,\text{arg}(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}')\rho(\textbf{x}') $$

with $\rho(\textbf{x}')$ being the particle density and $s$ the number of attached fluxes.
The new Hamiltonian reads

$$ H' = \int\text{d}^2 x  \frac{1}{2m} \psi^\dagger (-i\nabla + \textbf{A}_{\text{ext}}+\textbf{a})^2 \psi  + V' $$

where $\textbf{a} = -\nabla\chi$.

If I correctly understood, the new appearing gauge field $\textbf{a}$ counter acts as the external magnetic field in such a way that the CF behaves as an integer quantum Hall state.

My questions are now the following:

1. It is presented in Altland and Simons' book as if one strips away magnetic flux and attaches it to the microscopic fermions employing this gauge transformation. However, if this gauge transformation is with respect to the electronic charge, the vector potential should also transform to
   $ \textbf{A}_\text{ext} - \nabla \chi $
   and exactly cancel the newly acquired field?
2. In other sources (The scripts of David Tong), I read that the vector potential $\textbf{a}$ is some emergent statistical gauge field purely due to strong interaction within the material. Should I understand the flux attachment as attaching fluxes of this statistical gauge field?  If yes, $\textbf{a}$ is pure gauge. How does this can change the physics?